# Comparison Test / Limit Comparison Test

Tags: calculus

Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2+3 n-7}{n^3 - 2n +5}$ does not converge by the limit comparison test.

I don't know what would be the correct $b_{n}$ to compare with $a_{n}$ for this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose the harmonic series $\;\sum\frac1n\;$ , and then

$$\frac{\frac{n^2+3n-7}{n^3-2n+5}}{\frac1n}=\frac{n^3+3n^2-7n}{n^3-2n^2+5n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1$$

so your series converges iff the harmonic one does, but...

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\frac{n^{\text{The highest power of }n\text{ in the numerator}}}{n^{\text{The highest power of }n\text{ in the denominator}}}$$